# Change window keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard

So there's this gesture on touchpads where you move 4 fingers downward so you change between multiple windows of the same application. I'm working on an iMac now, so I don't have a touchpad, is there any keyboard command (or maybe a gesture on the magic mouse) to produce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the shortcut is <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.